# Python 3 String Method?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, strip

Is there anyway to strip or replace or anything like that from one index to another index within a single string?

For example, if I have a string like "first - second - third" and I want to remove the middle part (" - second - "), how could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string:

```
s = 'first - second - third'
```

and the possible solutions:

```
s.replace(' - second - ', '')
```

or

```
''.join(s.split(' - ')[::2])
```

or

```
''.join(s.split(' - second - '))
```

or if you know the indices:

```
s[:5] + s[-5:]
```

or just searching for the first and last space:

```
s[:s.index(' ')] + s[s.rindex(' ')+1:]
```

all of them return `'firstthird'`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't know what the middle part (which in this case is "second") of the string will be, but your second solution works perfect for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
"first - second - third".replace('- second -','')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the indices to remove are (i, j), then you could do with:

```
myStr[:i] + myStr[j+1:]
```